# nopcommerce 3.0 admin section is having prefix text as admin.module

Tags: nopcommerce

I am  using NopCommerce 3.0, when I login to administration section all menu text of admin section is having prefix  as .. (e.g Admin.Catalog, Admin.Catalog. products, admin.catalog.attributes.productattributes ,Admin.Sales  etc.) . I want to remove prefix  text  (I.e. Catalog, Products, Product Attributes…etc.). I have tried to remove it manually by replacing @T(“”) tags, this scenario works but it takes lot of time to modify.. Hence, suggest me other ways  to remove this prefix. Is there any kind of settings  available in Nopcommerce  settings?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to your working language is missing those resources. Find appropriate language file or create one yourself and import it to through your administration.